# How to validate if user exist inside IdentityServer4 after being authenticated from External Provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, single-page-application, identityserver4

I'm trying to find a proper way where I can inject a service to validate if user exists or registered in my application after being successfully authenticated from an external identity provider like Azure Active Directory. What I want to do is to redirect user to a custom error page or display an Unauthorized message if his account is not yet registered in my application.

I tried utilizing the IProfileService interface but it seems not the right way to go.

Here is my Startup.cs setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services
        .AddIdentityServer()
        .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
        .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers())
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients()) // Client was configured with RequireConsent = false, EnableLocalLogin = false,
        .AddProfileService<ProfileService>()
        .Services.AddTransient<IUserRepository,UserRepository>();

    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddOpenIdConnect("AAD", "Azure Active Directory", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
            options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
            options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/MyTenant";
            options.ClientId = "MyClientId";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false
            };

            options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;                    
        });
}


public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public ProfileService(IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository 
    }

    public Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        var user = _userRepository.FindByUser(context.Subject.Identity.Name);

        // This will display HTTP 500 instead of 401 
        if(user == null) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("You're not registered");

        // I add custom claims here

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

    public Task IsActiveAsync(IsActiveContext context) => Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Is there any available service or interface I can use where I can inject my user validation as well as allowing me to inject my user repository in that service? Is it possible to inject this kind of process inside IdentityServer4? Can someone point me in the right direction to accomplish my goal using IdentityServer4?

**Note:** Lets assume I have SPA web app and I have my own separate registration mechanism. I don't want to redirect back to my SPA if user doesn't exist and handle it inside IdentityServer4 instead. Btw, some of the code above are not included for brevity.

Comment: Are you using the [QuickStart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI)?

Comment: I assumed yes because I follow this [example](https://github.com/Crokus/aspnetcore-idsrv-aad-example), but I think it doesn't matter if I use QuickStart.UI or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IdentityServer4 QuickStart UI is configured to auto-provision local user accounts when signing-in through an external provider. That's all handled in [`ExternalController.Callback`](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/master/Quickstart/Account/ExternalController.cs#L88):

```
// lookup our user and external provider info
var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
if (user == null)
{
    // this might be where you might initiate a custom workflow for user registration
    // in this sample we don't show how that would be done, as our sample implementation
    // simply auto-provisions new external user
    user = AutoProvisionUser(provider, providerUserId, claims);
}
```

In your situation, you can perform whatever logic you need to perform instead of calling `AutoProvisionUser`. As this is a regular MVC action that's being executed, you have the ability to inject your own classes into `ExternalController`'s constructor or into `Callback` itself (using `[FromServices]`). Here's a rough idea of the changes you might want to make:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Callback([FromServices] IUserRepository userRepository)
{
    ...

    // lookup our user and external provider info
    var (user, provider, providerUserId, claims) = FindUserFromExternalProvider(result);
    if (user == null)
    {
        // We don't have a local user.
        return RedirectToAction("SomeAction", "SomeController");
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom logic in `ExternalLoginCallback` function in in `AccountController` if you are using ASP.NET Identity . After getting JWT token issued from Azure AD , you can decode the token ,get the user claims such as email/name :

```
if (remoteError != null)
{
    ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
}
// read external identity from the temporary cookie
var aadResult1 = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);
if (aadResult1?.Succeeded != true)
{
    throw new Exception("External authentication error");
}

// retrieve claims of the external user
var externalUser = aadResult1.Principal;
if (externalUser == null)
{
    throw new Exception("External authentication error");
}

// retrieve claims of the external user
var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();

// try to determine the unique id of the external user - the most common claim type for that are the sub claim and the NameIdentifier
// depending on the external provider, some other claim type might be used
var userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == JwtClaimTypes.Subject);
if (userIdClaim == null)
{
    userIdClaim = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");
}
if (userIdClaim == null)
{
    throw new Exception("Unknown userid");
}
```

Then you can write your service implement/logic in database to confirm whether user is already in database . If yes , login in user;if no , redirect user to confirmation/register view . Something like:

```
// Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync("YourProvider", userIdClaim.Value, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", "YourProvider");

    // delete temporary cookie used during external authentication
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme);

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
if (result.IsLockedOut)
{
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
}
else
{
    // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    ViewData["LoginProvider"] = "YourProvider";
    var email = claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Upn).Value;
    return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email });
}
```

It depends on you for how to link AD user to local database user .use Azure AD's object ID or UPN  .